# How to display eps format image in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to display EPS, SVG or WMF format image in `UIImageView`.
The images are not displayed in `UIImageView`, but .PNG format images are diplaying.

So, how can I use .EPS, .SVG or .WMF format images?

Answer (score 2):

`EPS`,`SVG` and `WMF` are not support by [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), thus you will have to use an third party library to load these files.

For `SVG` you could use [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/), it includes some nice example on how to use the library.